# gencpp/message_generator not running properly?

Tags: ros, generate-messages, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Help!

Trying to figure out what is wrong with my build of ROS, I have built a new custom message for my node but each time I catkin_make it and reference it to another project I have an empty header file when I inspect the #include and the code fails to compile, I know my configurations for package.xml and CMakeList.txt are correct as when I compile this on another machine it works and gencpp creates the code for it in the header, but my main working PC seems to not be using gencpp for what ever reason.

If anyone has encountered this issue before I would much appreciate some input.

This is the output of `catkin_make`:

```
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/USER/anaconda/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/USER/catkin_ws/src/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 5 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - spatial_dual_sdk_c
-- ~~  - lms400_driver
-- ~~  - phenoframework
-- ~~  - spatial_msg
-- ~~  - spatial_dual_driver
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_dual_sdk_c'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_dual_sdk_c)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'lms400_driver'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(lms400_driver)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- lms400_driver: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'phenoframework'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(phenoframework)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_msg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_msg)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- spatial_msg: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_dual_driver'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_dual_driver)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/USER/catkin_ws/src
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/USER/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 15%] [ 15%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target spatial_dual_sdk_c
[ 15%] [ 23%] [ 23%] Built target spatial_dual_sdk_c_rs232
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target packet_example_spatial_dual
[ 30%] Built target _lms400_driver_generate_messages_check_deps_lms400
[ 30%] Built target _spatial_msg_generate_messages_check_deps_Spatial
[ 46%] Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages_py
[ 53%] [ 69%] [ 76%] Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages_lisp
[ 84%] [ 92%] Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages_py
Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages_cpp
Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages_lisp
Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages_cpp
[ 92%] [ 92%] Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages
Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages
[100%] Built target spatial_dual_node
```

From this It looks like the messages were created successfully but the message headers are empty...
not sure what I'm missing here.

```
Ok Update, rebuilt my catkin workspace and environment, found this on `catkin_make`:

Looks like it fails every time I have to rebuild the build from scratch i.e. removing the contents of devel.

From `catkin_make --force`:

    -- Base path: /home/USER/catkin_ws
    -- Source space: /home/USER/catkin_ws/src
    -- Build space: /home/USER/catkin_ws/build
    -- Devel space: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel
    -- Install space: /home/USER/catkin_ws/install
    -- ####
    -- #### Running command: "cmake /home/USER/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/USER/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/USER/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/USER/catkin_ws/build"
    -- ####
    -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel
    -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
    -- This workspace overlays: /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
    -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/USER/anaconda/bin/python
    -- Using Debian Python package layout
    -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
    -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
    -- Call enable_testing()
    -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/USER/catkin_ws/build/test_results
    -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
    -- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
    -- catkin 0.6.14
    -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
    -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    -- ~~  traversing 5 packages in topological order:
    -- ~~  - spatial_dual_sdk_c
    -- ~~  - lms400_driver
    -- ~~  - spatial_msg
    -- ~~  - phenoframework
    -- ~~  - spatial_dual_driver
    -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_dual_sdk_c'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_dual_sdk_c)
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'lms400_driver'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(lms400_driver)
    -- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
    -- lms400_driver: 1 messages, 0 services
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_msg'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_msg)
    -- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
    -- spatial_msg: 1 messages, 0 services
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'phenoframework'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(phenoframework)
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'spatial_dual_driver'
    -- ==> add_subdirectory(spatial_dual_driver/spatial_dual_driver)
    -- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/USER/catkin_ws/build
    -- ####
    -- #### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/USER/catkin_ws/build"
    -- ####
    -- Linking C shared library /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libspatial_dual_sdk_c.so
    -- Linking C shared library /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libspatial_dual_sdk_c_rs232.so
    [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    [  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
    Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
    [  7%] [ 23%] Built target spatial_dual_sdk_c_rs232
    Built target spatial_dual_sdk_c
    [ 23%] [ 23%] Built target _lms400_driver_generate_messages_check_deps_lms400
    Built target _spatial_msg_generate_messages_check_deps_Spatial
    Linking C executable /home/USER/catkin_ws/devel/lib/spatial_dual_sdk_c/packet_example_spatial_dual
    [ 30%] [ 38%] [ 46%] [ 53%] [ 61%] [ 69%] Generating Python from MSG lms400_driver/lms400
    Generating C++ code from lms400_driver/lms400.msg
    Generating Python from MSG spatial_msg/Spatial
    Generating C++ code from spatial_msg/Spatial.msg
    Generating Lisp code from lms400_driver/lms400.msg
    Generating Lisp code from spatial_msg/Spatial.msg
    [ 76%] Built target packet_example_spatial_dual
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 49, in <module>
        srv_template_map)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 212, in generate_from_command_line_options
        generate_from_file(argv[1], options.package, options.outdir, options.emdir, options.includepath, msg_template_dict, srv_template_dict)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 153, in generate_from_file
    _generate_msg_from_file(input_file, output_dir, template_dir, search_path, package_name, msg_template_dict)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 98, in _generate_msg_from_file
    search_path)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 76, in _generate_from_spec
    interpreter = em.Interpreter(output=ofile, globals=g, options={em.RAW_OPT:True,em.BUFFERED_OPT:True})
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Interpreter'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 49, in <module>
    srv_template_map)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 212, in generate_from_command_line_options
        generate_from_file(argv[1], options.package, options.outdir, options.emdir, options.includepath, msg_template_dict, srv_template_dict)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 153, in generate_from_file
    _generate_msg_from_file(input_file, output_dir, template_dir, search_path, package_name, msg_template_dict)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 98, in _generate_msg_from_file
    search_path)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 76, in _generate_from_spec
    interpreter = em.Interpreter(output=ofile, globals=g, options={em.RAW_OPT:True,em.BUFFERED_OPT:True})
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Interpreter'
    make[2]: *** [/home/USER/catkin_ws/devel/include/lms400_driver/lms400.h] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [lms400_driver/CMakeFiles/lms400_driver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[2]: *** [/home/USER/catkin_ws/devel/include/spatial_msg/Spatial.h] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [spatial_dual_driver/spatial_msg/CMakeFiles/spatial_msg_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
    [ 84%] [ 92%] [ 92%] [ 92%] Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages_lisp
    Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages_lisp
    Generating Python msg __init__.py for lms400_driver
    Generating Python msg __init__.py for spatial_msg
    [ 92%] Built target lms400_driver_generate_messages_py
    [ 92%] Built target spatial_msg_generate_messages_py
    make: *** [all] Error 2



---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220449/gencpp/message_generator-not-running-properly?/) by [new2ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21455/new2ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2015-11-04


Post score: 0

---

### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-11-07**:\
Just a wild guess: do you also have `-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/USER/anaconda/bin/python` on your other machines? If not, then I would try to build with the python that comes with ubuntu. (don't forget do delete the build folder because cmake caches this path)

**Comment by [new2ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21455/new2ros/) on 2015-11-08**:\
Thanks for the response,
Turns out, you were correct, the second I removed the Anaconda from my PATH environment the messages were generated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a wild guess: do you also have `-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/USER/anaconda/bin/python` on your other machines? If not, then I would try to build with the python that comes with ubuntu. (don't forget do delete the build folder because cmake caches this path)

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1